# Omitting prepositions with the relative pronoun "where"

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I am having some doubts about the use of "transferred" without its preposition. Does "where" as a relative pronoun always do without prepositions? Shouldn't we say "transferred to"?

> This transcript above was issued at the candidate's request. It was
>   presented to the Faculty of Arts, University of Athens **where he
>   transferred and completed** his bachelor's degree.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a good answer to your question, because this is an area where different speakers differ in complicated ways.

There's a [Monkees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkees) song with the line, "Mary, where're you going to?", which to me sounds very awkward at best; I would always say "Where're you going?" (There are other cases, though, where "where […] to?" *does* sound fine to me. For example, the complete question "Where to?", meaning roughly "Where do you want me to take you?", is much more natural than simply "Where?".)

But conversely, I find "Where are you at?" perfectly natural (albeit informal), and when I went to college, I was surprised to discover that students from other parts of the country found it very strange.

---

For the sentence that you quote,

> It was presented to the Faculty of Arts, University of Athens where he transferred and completed his bachelor's degree.

I have problem with "where he transferred" — there's no need for a *to* — and I have no problem with "where he […] completed his bachelor's degree" — there's no need for an *at*.

But I find the full compound clause "where he transferred and completed his bachelor's degree" to be awkward, because it seems to be simultaneously using the word *where* in two different ways: both as "to which" and as "at which". But given the variation I mentioned above, I would not be at all surprised to hear that there are other speakers who find nothing strange about it.

(Full disclosure: although I grew up in the Midwestern US, my family spoke both English and Hebrew at home. Since Hebrew consistently distinguishes "to which" from "at which", I may be more attuned to the (potential) distinction than monolingual speakers, and this *may* be part of why I find your sentence awkward. But since plenty of people say "where […] to?" or "where […] at?" in various contexts, it's clear that many monolingual English speakers find a distinction natural, too.)

This variation, by the way, seems to be specific to *where*; *at* and *to* are basically *never* used with the related adverbs *here* and *there*. It's also mostly specific to *at* and *to*; I'm fairly confident that no one would object to *from where*, *from here*, and *from there*.

Comment: Does the sentence as it is sound good to you? Does it give away nonnative phrasing?

Comment: @asef: I find the sentence a bit awkward, but I think the writer is very likely a native speaker. By the way, I've edited my answer to better address your question by clarifying that "where he transferred" is fine, and does not require a *to*.

Comment: I'd be very grateful if you proposed an alternative phrasing.

Comment: @asef: I'd probably rewrite it a bit more thoroughly, so some context would help. If "he [...] completed his bachelor's degree" at the Faculty of Arts, then why does a transcript need to be presented to them? Shouldn't they already have his transcript?